# OpenCV Encoding to H264 changing original RGB pixel values for gray images

Tags: opencv, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, h.265

I have the following issue:
I'm creating a uniform gray color video (for testing) using OpenCV VideoWriter. The output video will reproduce a constant image where all the pixels must have the same value x (25, 51, 76,... and so on).
When I generate the video using MJPG Encoder:

```
vw = cv2.VideoWriter('./videos/input/gray1.mp4',
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),
        fps,(resolution[1],resolution[0]))
```

and read the output using the VideoCapture class, everything just works fine. I got a frame array with all pixel values set to (25,51,76 and so on).
However when I generate the video using HEV1 (H.265) or also H264:

```
vw = cv2.VideoWriter('./videos/input/gray1.mp4',
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'HEV1'),
        fps,(resolution[1],resolution[0]))
```

I run into the following issue. The frame I got in BGR format follows the next configuration:

- The **blue channel value** is the expected value (x) minus 4 (25-4=21, 51-4=47, 76-4=72, and so on).
- The **green channel** is the expected value (x) minus 1 (25-1=24, 51-1=50, 76-1=75).
- The **red channel** is the expected value (x) minus 3 (25-3=22, 51-3=48, 76-3=73).

Notice that the value is reduced with a constant value of 4,1,3, independently of the pixel value (so there is a constant effect). 
What I could explain is a pixel value dependable feature, instead of a fixed one.
What is worse is that if I choose to generate a video with frames consisting in every color (pixel values [255 0 0],[0 255 0] and [0 0 255]) I get the corresponding outputs values ([251 0 0],[0 254 0] and [0 0 252])
I though that this relation was related to the grayscale Y value, where:

Y = 76/256 * RED + 150/256 * GREEN + 29/256 * BLUE

But this coefficients are not related with the output obtained. Maybe the problem is the reading with VideoCapture?

EDIT:
In case that I want to have the same output value for the pixels (Ej: [10,10,10] experimentally I have to create a img where the red and blue channel has the green channel value plus 2:

```
value = 10
img = np.zeros((resolution[0],resolution[1],3),dtype=np.uint8)+value
    img[:,:,2]=img[:,:,2]+2
    img[:,:,1]=img[:,:,1]+0
    img[:,:,0]=img[:,:,0]+2
```

Anyone has experience this issue? It is related to the encoding process or just that OpenCV treats the image differently, prior encoding, depending on the fourcc parameter value?

Comment: Don't those codecs use lossy compression by default?

Comment: @dan-mašek I thought this in the first place. It is possible that MJPG encoder is the only one that does a lossy compression but with high quality profile within OpenCV? Cause the rest of encoders generates the same output. for example for input [255,255,255] with MJPG I got [255,255,255] as expected, and with HEVC I got [250,253,251] (weird). And what it is weirder is that if I  process the output video with the MJPG encoder and convert it to HEVC with profile set as main (using ffmpeg) I got [255,255,255] as expected, so I don't know what exactly is happening with the OpenCV library.

Comment: How do you make bgr(25,51,76) a grey image?

Comment: Maybe it is just an approximation: YCC is used, but because speed, calculations with integers are preffered, so ... Try few different encoder, and maybe you should fill a bug.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry for the confusion but there were three different images bgr(25,25,25), bgr(51,51,51) and bgr(76,76,76)

Comment: Why don't you try extracting a frame from your OpenCV-written video with `ffmpeg` to see if OpenCV wrote it differently from how you expected? And also writing a video with `ffmpeg` and seeing what OpenCV extracts? Then you would know if it is the encoder or the decoder, or the whole concept that is at fault.